# Avoid regenerating files that won't change

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile with several rules of this form

```
protolist.c: $(PROTOCOLS) Makefile src/genmodtable.sh
    $(SHELL) $(srcdir)/src/genmodtable.sh \
        $@ $(filter-out %Makefile %genmodtable.sh, $^)
```

As the name implies, `protolist.c` winds up containing a list of all the "protocols" defined by the `.c` files in `$(PROTOCOLS)`.  The contents of this file do formally depend on everything in `$(PROTOCOLS)`, the Makefile, and the generator script, but it's very rare for the file to *actually* change when one of those `.c` files is edited.  Therefore, `genmodtable.sh` is coded to not change the timestamp of `protolist.c` if it's not going to make any change to its contents.  This causes Make to skip rebuilding `protolist.o` and its dependencies when it's not really necessary.

That all works fine; the *problem* is that, because `protolist.c` now appears to be out of date with respect to *its* dependencies, Make thinks it has to try to regenerate `protolist.c` on every run. This isn't a performance issue -- the script is very fast -- but it is confusing behavior.  I dimly recall an idiom, involving timestamp files, that could be used to stop Make from doing this, but I have not been able to reconstruct it or find it described anywhere.  Does anyone know what it is?

(Also if anyone can suggest how to get rid of that silly `$(filter-out ...)` construct, that would be helpful, as that is the only GNUmakeism in this Makefile.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears similar to an issue with Fortran programming and make, involving the files generated when compiling a module. (Not relevant, other than that is where I picked up how to do this.)

What you want is have make compare the timestamp of `protolist.o` to the timestamp of `protolist.c`, which remains 'old', and make the decision to run the recipe for `protolist.c`, depending on the timestamp of, well, a timestamp file, which gets updated each time the recipe is run.
In order to make this work, you have to link the two together with an empty rule.

```
protolist.o: protolist.c
    [...]

protolist.c: protolist.c.time ;

protolist.c.time: $(PROTOCOLS) Makefile src/genmodtable.sh
    $(SHELL) $(srcdir)/src/genmodtable.sh \
        protolist.c $(filter-out %Makefile %genmodtable.sh, $^)
    touch protolist.c.time
```

In my own makefiles, I have to declare the timestamp files as prerequisites of the special target `.PRECIOUS`, to prevent make from deleting them, but I'm using pattern rules; I'm not 100% sure, but I think this isn't necessary when using explicit rules, like here.

To avoid the `$(filter-out ...)` construct, can you not simply replace it with `$(PROTOCOLS)`?
(Although, personally, I would stick to [Paul's First Rule of Makefiles](http://mad-scientist.net/make/rules.html): Don't hassle with writing portable makefiles, use a portable make instead.)

Comment: This does the job - the '`protolist.c: protolist.c.time ;`' construct was the bit I was missing.  Thanks!  As for using `$(PROTOCOLS)` directly, that breaks VPATH builds; `$^` does pathname substitution for files not found relative to the current directory, but regular Make variables don't.